# Parse json using python multiple dictionary

Tags: python, json

I need to get the value of the keywords from the json file below. Like:

```
output = ['abc,'cde']
```

Json file structure looks like :

```
d = [{
    "response": {"docs": [
        {"keywords": [{"value": "abc"}]},
        {"keywords": [{"value": "cde"}]}
    ]}
}]
```

I have tried the below. I believe it's redundant though since I get only one level of ["response"]["docs"].

```
keywords = []
data = json.load(data_file)
for i in data:
    keywords.append(i["response"]["docs"][0]["keywords"])
keyword_Value = [g['value'] for d in keywords for g in d]
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: is the key "response" used multiple times or is this a typo? above data is not a valid python dict.

Comment: @leovp edited question

Comment: @PJSantoro sorry edited question

Answer (score 0):

There's a JSON encoder/decoder built in to Python. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Something like

```
import json
with open ('path/to/your_data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
```

Comment: I already have the data. I have read the json file and need only the list of specific values as described above.

Comment: You use it as a native Python data structure and loop over the keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using an external library, this task is quite easy using [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) like:

```
import jmespath
keywords = jmespath.search('[].response.docs[].keywords[].value', data)
```

**Code:**

```
data = [{
    "response": {"docs": [
        {"keywords": [{"value": "abc"}]},
        {"keywords": [{"value": "cde"}]}
    ]}
}]

import jmespath
keywords = jmespath.search('[].response.docs[].keywords[].value', data)

print(keywords)
```

**Results:**

```
['abc', 'cde']
```